# How to fetch only one record from DB and to not store it in array in DRUPAL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
 $id = db_select('adc_global_test', 'a')
        ->fields('a', array('global_var'))
        ->condition('index', $i, '=')
        ->execute()->fetchAll();
```

instead of fetchAll what can i use to get this record not in a array.
i want this record in a variable. Like i have to use this :-

$name = "adc".$id;

Comment: What kind of DB do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fetchField()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchField/7):

```
$id = db_select('adc_global_test', 'a')
  ->fields('a', array('global_var'))
  ->condition('index', $i, '=')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```